# Is it possible to get a ref of the slider-thumb in input slider?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript

I want to apply a tooltips to show the value of the thumb in a range slider.

I know there's a way to do it with calculating the position and such, but I have a pre-build tooltips component that can take the ref and display it at the position.

If I get the input ref, the tooltip doesn't move with the thumb and just stay in place in the middle. Is there a way to retrieve the ref for the thumb specifically?

```
        <input
          ref={localRef}
          className={'dig-Slider-input'}
          type="range"
          role="slider"
        />
```

tried getting the local ref of input. Needs to get the local ref of thumb.

Comment: No. You'll have to reimplement it based on input value. It that helps, when the range is at [minimum], the center of the thumb is `0.5rem` from the left, when the range is at [maximum], the center of the thumb is `0.5rem` from the right. The rest is simply based on % of progress between min and max.